# Assign types on setState to React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working on the project that uses TypeScript and React and I'm trying to restrict the data based on interface assigned to state.

I have assigned the type **IState interface** to the state which has **uiForm** key assigns with type **studentForm interface**. But when I am assigning the wrong structured data or with wrong key which is not present in the studentForm Interface to uiForm key, it gets assigned without validating the type.

My code looks like this:

```
interface IProps {}

interface studentForm {
    label: string,
    type: string,
    sequen: string
}

interface IState {
    uiForm: Array < studentForm >
}

export default class AddStudent extends React.Component < IProps, IState > {
    state: IState = {
        uiForm: []
    }
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('./assets/studentForm.json').then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                this.setState({
                    uiForm: data
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
}
```

I am trying to assign the uiForm with below object

studentForm.json:

```
{ 
   "label":"Admission No.",
   "type":"text",
   "sequence":1
}
```

Ideally, it should not be assigned but it is assigning

What would be the proper way to assign the types to state/setState?
Thank you.

Comment: Did the answer down under solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is not the crux here - if you look at the type signature of [`fetch`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L19944), you see that it returns a Response object with `Body` interface like this:

```
interface Body {
  ...
  json(): Promise<any>;
}
```

So `data` effectively becomes `any` typed and `any` can be assigned to ... anything ..., which makes `this.setState({ uiForm: data })` properly typed.

If you need to validate the `fetch` result first, annotate `data` with type `unknown` and then do a run-time check with [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) (branching logic) or [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) (assert/invariant logic; TS 3.7). An assertion example:

```
export default class AddStudent extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('./assets/studentForm.json').then((res) => res.json())
            // type data as unknown
            .then((data: unknown) => {
                // assertion function narrows data type or throws error
                assertStudentFormArray(data)
                // data type narrowed to Array<studentForm> here
                this.setState({
                    uiForm: data
                })
            })
    }
}

function assertStudentFormArray(args: any): asserts args is IState["uiForm"] {
    // do your validation here ...
    if (!Array.isArray(args)) throw new Error("Got no array...")
    if (args.some(arg => !("label" in arg))) throw new Error("Got no studentform...")
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=41&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOASQAUcwBnOAb1Ln7goAXHA4woVAOakAvuSo06DUTACuAEyTUAYtDy8BcADYoARkiMixEypIA0fATACeYJFfFSHhjkgCOqloeNtJyFNS09GiMTADKMCg0PI78qsC6UCAiAIJQUCjOADxiGlowGSAAfLKkSAAekLBwmvSqRvBoJhxc2erq8aXUcPU0lOpcyOgwAHQAwriQlGWFrOwcdszxiUiVyT4JNCJxB4wAvHuGAmkVIgDaALopcHKGaBCU1qoY0AAUYGtHNgQTgASgul1EqjcUD%20axBAG4ni8BG9wO8ygARYDqACyEFU1B%20YIMELgmCQMDQAAsfgByaYAehQ3QpHAZJU0Oj00wAVhx3rSQdMYFStD8fkQOGDTrtJbz%20ZQiSCnqS4MLRYqfupEsI4ASANaUCAAd0o0t2JNVEOZvlgA055T0Wp1yqtpJFwA4018MC2NB%20lrdpOuehE2oSKqDMldUZjbumaES1J%20tCgcBl4KD-DeHwgRiQ0yMEEkKbyCMjEOjSJqpEwBIwwHeghZdrUDoqPxQUEkHBEKEozhBfZbMC4XZ7cE9mxOt3wIcy%20HumYZDOaEDgznxaYAbigjNjEo3KHBRUQ1dNpk9gJg4D8AIS5fLOaaex8FTvdqVgkU4Y1wJZ-gAonkvz4AA4hA8BGoIeQFBe0z4HGk43h%20PbergSCoemux3j8%20AmOYRj4JOx7jiC5FwD%20Jr-kgQEgTC4GQf%2064cmUmDcheiGyEAA)